# Is there an RSS feed available for new Amazon Prime Instant video releases?

Tags: rss

Is there an RSS feed available (official or otherwise) for newly-added Amazon Prime Instant Video selections?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no RSS feed which Amazon provides. However, you may be able to use some kind of browser extension such as [Page Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd) to monitor the page for changes.